# Add values from existing values, Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to initialize a simple python dictionary as shown below:

```py
dictionary = {
               'a':'dftyj',
               'b':'dftyj'+'__29July2021'
          }
```

As you see `dictionary['b']` is nothing but `dictionary['a']` + random string. I was wondering if I could use any sort of pointer to get value from the already existing properties of the dictionary?

Comment: Define the value for `a` as a seperate variable before defining the dictionary or define b after making the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible to do while you're creating the dictionary.
You have to first create a dictionary and then get something out of it.

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['a'] = 'dftyj'
dictionary['b'] = dictionary['a'] + '__29July2021'
```

Comment: This ain't exactly what I was looking for but still thanks for the idea.